# AWS nginx/1.16.1 - "413 Request Entity Too Large" and Spring boot jar

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Jave project and tried to upload 2 MB file on AWS EBS and getting following error.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>

</html>
```

**This question looks duplicate however all old questions and correct answer not working with new EBS/ngnx version.**

Added file on all suggested folder structure but no solution is working with nginx/1.16.1 , please find following image .

[image]

Inside file added

```
      client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending few hrs finally resolved issue .

**Issue 1:**

Spring boot by default ignore all folders so weather you can copy any file and directory structure not going to deployed in EBS.

in short ".ebextensions" ignored while jar created,in order to fix added following plugins into POM

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/" overwrite="false">
                                <fileset dir="./" includes=".ebextensions/**"/>
                            </copy>
                            <zip compress="false" destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**Issue 2:**

Following configuration worked for me

```
Path : root /.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d
File : proxy.config

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 50M;
      client_body_buffer_size 16k;

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Comment: So i added the dependency as mentioned in pom and then where i need to add this file 2 which is related to issue 2 , as i am still getting the error , i added file in .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d and then 01_files.config and then the above file which u have put in issue 2 but it still does not work

Comment: .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d create on root level

Comment: but this file needs to create in spring boot application right in src/main/resources/ebextensions/nginx/conf.d right ?

Comment: on root folder outside src

Comment: see here if you use java 11 or higher https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077616/springboot-fails-to-deploy-after-adding-ebextensions-for-ngingx-ssl-an-error

Answer (score 1):

if have added  nginx.conf

inside a
`client_max_body_size 20M;`

sites-available/defual  or your active config file

else you using sperate config for a reverse  proxy  that was not correct config file check you update client_max_body_size in right file

```
$ sudo systemctl reload nginx.service
```

if change correctly then restart an Nginx service

I will suggest a test without proxy may be limitations on the tomcat server you have to change it.